# How to sent notification email to user avoiding to be marked as SPAM by phpgmailer?

Tags: php, email, gmail, spam-prevention, email-spam

I`m using PHPGmailer to sent some important notification for registered user. The email is Google App powered.

here is my configuration for sent email function with PHPGMailer class:

```
function send_mail($to, $subject, $content)
{
    $mail = new PHPGMailer();
    $mail->Username = 'info@domain.com'; 
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxxx';
    $mail->From = 'info@domain.com'; 
    $mail->FromName = 'domain';
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = $content;
    $mail->Send();  
}
```

Is it good enough to sent notification and prevent to be marked as spam? Or add some more additional configuration and settings?

Comment: You didn't say whether you are routing the email via the Google MTA, whether the MX points to Google's servers nor what the SPF for the domain is.

Comment: @symcbean what`s Google MTA? In order to create a Google App`s Gmail account, it have to change the MX record from domain setting before. Is it enough for that?

Answer (score 1):

A big part of preventing emails from being marked as spam is your mail server setup.

A google search for 'prevent emails from being marked as spam' returns a bunch of info.